# "None" is returned on the request in Python Asyncio

Tags: python, async-await, fetch, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have started learning asyncio in Python, want to fetch data from a URL. When i print the fixtures in fixtures.py and result in utils.py, i am getting "None"

**FILE fixtures.py**

```
import asyncio
from utils import fetch

class Fixture:
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session

    async def get_fixture(self):
        url = "*************"
        fixtures = await fetch(self.session, url)

        print (fixtures)
```

**FILE utils.py**

```
import asyncio

async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        result = await response.json()
        print(result)
        return result
```

**FILE main.py**

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from fixtures import Fixture

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        fix = Fixture(session)
        #print(fix)
        fixture = await fix.get_fixture()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Are you sure that URL returns a JSON response with data in it…?

Comment: @deceze 
if I `print(response)`, i get :

<CIMultiDictProxy('Connection': 'close', 'Content-Length': '0', 'Server': 'Varnish', 'Retry-After': '0', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Date': 'Mon, 28 Sep 2020 07:18:59 GMT', 'Via': '1.1 varnish', 'X-Served-By': 'cache-bom4731-BOM', 'X-Cache': 'MISS', 'X-Cache-Hits': '0', 'X-Timer': 'S1601277539.225160,VS0,VE0')>

Comment: `'Content-Length': '0'`… Doesn't seem to be anything in it.

Comment: @deceze if I try out the same without asyncio i am getting a response: 


`import requests

url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/‘

r = requests.get(url)
json = r.json()
json.keys()
`



**RESPONSE**
`dict_keys(['events', 'game_settings', 'phases', 'teams', 'total_players', 'elements', 'element_stats', 'element_types'])`